# SQL sort by 4 columns with 1 column sorted by True and False Both

Tags: sql, mysql, join, sql-order-by

I'm looking to sort a list of salespersons which needs to be sorted by 4 columns - IsAvailable DESC, EmailStatus DESC, FirstName ASC, LastName ASC.

- IsAvailable (makes switch button editable) - this means if the salesperson
  is ready to attend the appointment (sorting - True first then false)
- EmailStatus (shows red icon if False) - this means if the
  salesperson has valid mailbox. (sorting - true first then false but
  when false, the isAvailable should also be false).
- FirstName
  and LastName - first name and last name in ASC order

**Current sorted list:** 
[image]

**Required sorting :** 
[image]

**Required sorting list in words:**

1. First it should be Active with IsAvailable True & EmailStatus True & First ASC & Last ASC
2. Then it should be Active or Inactive with IsAvailable True/False but with EmailStatus False, First and Last ASC
3. Last should be IsAvailable False and EmailStatus True (which is Inactive switch without the red icon), First and Last ASC

**Code I Tried:**

```
SELECT 
    {Collaborator}.*,
    {ShowroomMember}.*,
    {WorkRole}.*,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT({ShowroomMember}.[Id])
        FROM 
            {ShowroomMember}
        WHERE 
            {ShowroomMember}.[CollaboratorId] = {Collaborator}.[Id]    
    )
FROM {ShowroomMember}
    INNER JOIN {Collaborator} ON {Collaborator}.[Id] = {ShowroomMember}.[CollaboratorId]
    INNER JOIN {WorkRole} ON {ShowroomMember}.[WorkRoleId] = {WorkRole}.Id
WHERE
    **{ShowroomMember}.[ShowroomId] = @ShowroomId
ORDER BY {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable] DESC, {Collaborator}.[EmailStatus] DESC, 
{Collaborator}.[FirstName] ASC, {Collaborator}.[LastName] ASC**
```

Comment: Possibly downvoted due to you using pictures rather than editable text - people want to be able to copy data so they can try out a solution. Also, having pictures that display icons rather than the actual data values is particularly unhelpful. Though I agree that downvotes/votes to close with no explanation are often unhelpful - unfortunately just one of the "features" of this forum

Comment: Please update your question with sample data of the actual values in your table (as editable text) and the result you want to achieve. The sort order is determined by the columns you list, the order they are listed in and the DESC/ASC value. If your required sort order can't be achieved using the columns you have available then you would need to create calculated column(s) which when sorted do give the result you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies to the community for using pictures. 
For anyone looking for the solution, I was able to solve this by using `CASE`. It was a long trial-and-error as the the sorting was not according to solution due to multiple times failing the First Name and Last Name in mixture with IsAvailable and EmailStatus. The code might be ugly but it works. You can update and make it look `pretty`.

I've used multiple `WHEN` with same condition to apply 3 different sorting for same conditions.

Solution:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN {Collaborator}.[EmailStatus]=1 AND {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable]=1 THEN {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable] END DESC,
CASE WHEN {Collaborator}.[EmailStatus]=1 AND {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable]=1 THEN {Collaborator}.[FirstName] END ASC,
CASE WHEN {Collaborator}.[EmailStatus]=1 AND {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable]=1 THEN {Collaborator}.[LastName] END ASC,

CASE WHEN {Collaborator}.[EmailStatus]=1 AND {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable]=0 THEN {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable] END ASC,
CASE WHEN {Collaborator}.[EmailStatus]=1 AND {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable]=0 THEN {Collaborator}.[FirstName] END ASC,
CASE WHEN {Collaborator}.[EmailStatus]=1 AND {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable]=0 THEN {Collaborator}.[LastName] END ASC,

CASE
    WHEN {Collaborator}.[EmailStatus]=0 AND ({ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable]=0 OR {ShowroomMember}.[IsAvailable]=1)
    THEN {Collaborator}.[FirstName] END ASC
```

The Last `CASE` holds the sorting of salesperson in the list when changing the status from inactive to active or vice-versa. If I would use the `CASE` like the I used for other conditions in the code above, it would sort it differently, hence I had to combine the True and False of IsAvailable together using `OR` to **preserve** the sorting of the salesperson according to the first and last name.